# Wrap specific text between span element with a class with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I need a Javascript function that will automatically wrap a specific text (Stefano) between a span element with the class="cec".

Here the HTML:

```
<main>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</b>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h2>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h3>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

and here how it should be transformed:

```
<main>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</b>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h2>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h3>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla <span class="cec">Stefano</span> Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

Consider it will be done in a Wordpress environment so I will avoid JQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't tried with regex, please do.

Comment: Please go read [ask] before asking your next question here. This is not a place to get code written for you - you are supposed to show an actual effort to try and solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `replace` and a regular expression.

`var container` selects the element with your markup.

`/g` in the regex is for global replacement.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('div');

container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.replace(/Stefano/g, '<span class="cec">Stefano</span>');
```

```css
.cec{color: red}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</b>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h2>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h3>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: If the div containg an image with an ALT tag as Stefano it will create strange results...
Original:
`<img width="62" height="62" src="/img/logo-LB.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Stefano">`
After Javascript:
`<img width="62" height="62" src="/img/logo-LB.png" class="custom-logo" alt="<span class=" cec"="">Stefano"&gt;`

Comment: You did not mentioned an image.

Comment: Will this `<img>` be inside of `<p>`? If not you can select just all p tags.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did is adding an ID to the container element. This makes it easier (and more solid) to select the right element.

The next challenge is to define the right regular expression to match "Stefano" in all child elements of the container. I've used the `\b` anchor which allows me to search for whole words in a string.

`\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters". - [source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

The last step is to loop through all child nodes and wrap the matched string in a `<span>`.

```js
// get the container <div>
const container = document.getElementById('container');

// define the regular expression to match the string that needs to be wrapped
const match = /\bStefano\b/g;

// loop through each child element of the container
// and wrap "Stefano" in a <span>
for (child of container.children) {
  child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML.replace(match, '<span class="cec">Stefano</span>');
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="container">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</b>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h2>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h3>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla Stefano Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: If the div containg an image with an ALT tag as Stefano it will create strange results...
Original:
`<img width="62" height="62" src="/img/logo-LB.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Stefano">`
After Javascript:
`<img width="62" height="62" src="/img/logo-LB.png" class="custom-logo" alt="<span class=" cec"="">Stefano"&gt;`